Is there any way to import Javascript value that was not exported
I work with a system built in Salesforce, which includes Aura helper files. As described in the docs, each file consists of a single object literal in brackets, with functions as properties, e.g.
({
    someHelperMethod: function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }
})

I'd like to add unit tests for some of these functions, if possible without first editing the helper file, to ease adoption of JS unit tests in this context and minimise the risk of regressions to untested code. As far as I can see Salesforce does not have any built-in system for unit testing JS, so I would run these tests outside of Salesforce before deploying.
Is there any way that my test code that I will run in e.g. my node CLI can refer to and exercise someHelperMethod, or is it impossible since it was not exported? If it's impossible does anyone want to speculate on how Salesforce is accessing the object? Would I need to make a script to wrap the object in something like "export default [fileContent];" and write that out to a new JS file?

IIUC, you should be able to define a test function in the controller that uses the helper. It will receive the helper as an argument, then you can call helper.someHelperMethod()

@Barmar I don't think that helps me. It doesn't seem to get me any closer to be able to call someHelperMethod from inside something like a spec file that I'm going to run with the Jasmine test runner, completely unrelated to Salesforce. If I make a function in the controller how would I call that controller function?

Alternatively, is there any simple and safe change that could be made to the Aura helper file to allow it to be used from e.g. Jasmine without breaking the Aura controller that relies on it.

One way to solve this is to read the content of the file as a string and then write it into a separate file and add the export whiles writing to the file in the manner below:


const fs = require('fs');

// Read the original helper aura file file content
const originalContent = fs.readFileSync('path/to/your/originalHelper.js', 'utf8');

// Wrap the content and prepare it for export
const wrappedContent = `module.exports = ${originalContent}`;

// Write the wrapped content to a new file
fs.writeFileSync('path/to/your/exportedHelper.js', wrappedContent);



Afterwards you can write the test for this file instead.

You can also just do something like const helper = eval(originalContent);

Thanks, looks like this could work - either with a script to run the fs version before the test suite every time to make sure I'm testing the current code, or the eval version. Will have to see if it would be much slower than a standard module import.
I think my other option is moving the code out of the Aura component into an LWC component, since the latter is more like a standard JS module. https://medium.com/@strusov/how-to-share-a-code-between-aura-and-lightning-web-component-a1e1b86f3b61

Probably better with indirect eval: const helper = eval?.(originalContent);
